# Plot two gaussian lines for each histogram over double histogram

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting two histograms on same subplot:

```
n,x,_ = ax2.hist([months, months1], bins = bins, density = 'True')
```

and I'd like to plot two gaussian lines over each histogram:

```
density = stats.gaussian_kde(months)
density1 = stats.gaussian_kde(months1)
ax2.plot(x[0], density(x[0)])
ax2.plot(x[1], density1(x[1]))
```

But returned x is not a list of arrays. It's just a single array.
How can  it be done?

Thank you.

Comment: It's the same array, so just use `x` itself.

Comment: Got it right! Thank you!